# Eigen value system? solution

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

I have the following system.

$AW = \lambda B W$

Where $A,B,W$ are matrices and $\lambda$ is a scalar. The values of $A,B$ and $\lambda$ are known. $B$ is invertible.

This is a solution to an optimization problem, where I am trying to find $W$ by setting $\frac{\partial J}{\partial W} = 0$.

How can I find the solution of W? (could you provide any references?)
Any easy way to implement it in Matlab?

Comment: This is a generalized eigenvalue problem. Are A, B, symmetric? Is B positive definite? If so, there are ways of handling this. If not, then it gets very difficult as you may get complex eigenvalues $\lambda$ ...

Comment: @Angelo no it isn't; OP has specified that $\lambda$ is known

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
AW = \lambda BW \implies\\
(A - \lambda B)W = 0
$$
Thus, to find $W$, we should simply ensure that each column $x$ of $W$ is a solution to the homogeneous system of equations
$$
(A - \lambda B)x = 0
$$
In Matlab, use `null(A - lambda * B)` to find a basis to this solutions space.

Comment: and find the generalized eigenvalues i.e., solve ${\rm det} (A-\lambda B)=0$ for $\lambda$.

Comment: @Angelo why would we solve for $\lambda$ if $\lambda$ is known?

Comment: missed that, thanks. Then we need to find the generalized eigenvectors, should they exist. A necessary condition is that said determinant vanish. Then it's just a large system of linear equations...

Comment: @Angelo there has been no indication that these matrices are square

Comment: I need more coffee...

Comment: Thanks for the answers. If $\lambda = 1$, are A and B same (in may case it is not)? or (A-B) and W are orthogonal?

Comment: I guess that this would work only if $\lambda$ was very accurate. If $\lambda$ would be known with some loose accuracy then it might be better to compute the SVD and use a different drop tolerance for small eigenvalues (or taking the singular vector associated with $\sigma_{\min}$ if $\sigma_{\min}\ll\sigma_{\max}$). `null` compares them with $\max\{m,n\}\,\epsilon\,\sigma_{\max}$ so this might work only if $\lambda$ is very accurate. It is not clear to me though how $\lambda$ can be computed without providing a corresponding eigenvector solution.

Comment: @user570593 I don't understand your question

Comment: Sorry.I dont have a very good maths background. In my case I can write the final solution as XW = 0, where X is a known matrix. I want to find W and I need to select a set of columns/rows from W as my final solution. In that case can I use any svd decomposition/eigen value decomposition of X to find W?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel with square systems, it is common to obtain $\lambda$ without an eigenvector via QR decomposition; I don't know if that applies here. Good thought with the SVD.

Comment: True, with the QR algorithm.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel QR algorithm, yes, that's what I meant.  Didn't know that about the `edit` command

Comment: @user570593 If $X = U \Sigma V^*$, you can select the columns of $V$ corresponding to $\sigma_i = 0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: The question states that $B$ is invertible. For me that _is_ an indication the matrices (except $W$) are square.

Comment: @Angelo my bad; you were right about being able to take the determinant.  See ML's comment above.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen perhaps it is I, then, who needs coffee.

Comment: If such a $W$ exists at all for the given $\lambda$ then $\lambda$ must be a generalized eigenvalue (and so $W$ is a generalized eigenvector). How was $\lambda$ found at the outset?